# How do I make pdoc preserve whitespace?

Tags: python, documentation, epydoc, pdoc

I'm trying to generate documentation using pdoc, where my docstrings look like this:

```
"""
I am a description of what a method does

:param param1: an integer
:param param2: a str
"""
```

I found this question: [How to preserve line breaks when generating python docs using sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-generating-python-docs-using-sphinx) but the suggestion of prefixing each line with | did not work for me (it just showed up like this)

```
| :param param1: an integer | :param param2: a str
```

any ideas short of using \n at the end of every line?

Comment: What is `pdoc`? -- Also what happens if you move the first line up a line (e.g. `"""I am a ...`)?  That's the style recommended by [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) so most tools that do docstring parsing should understand it.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools pdoc is a replacement for epydoc. Moving the first line up does nothing for the subsequent lines.

Comment: Ahh -- I see.  Thanks.  What happens if you try to tell `pdoc` to use reStructuredText the same way you would tell `epydoc`?  e.g. add [`__docformat__ = 'restructuredtext en'`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/othermarkup.html) at the top of the module?

Comment: same result as before

Comment: Oh, Your documentation isn't in strict restructured text format... it'd be `:param: an integer`  and `:param: a string`.  And if that doesn't work (with the `__docformat__` above, you could try the epydoc format:  `@type param1: int` (newline) `@param param1: Somthing about the integer here.`  -- Of course, you maybe already know this since you're trying to find a way to preserve newlines -- But I figured I'd point it out just in case.

Comment: using `@param param1:` instead of `:param param1:` (which is what I was really doing, copied it wrong, will update) didn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe late, but IIRC pdoc does not use restructuredText; instead it use markdown. For the rest I am not sure I can help you

Answer (score 8):

So, I've been having the same issue.  Just figured it out.  [Pdoc uses markdown](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#use-numpydoc-or-google-docstrings).  You want to use a softbreak in mark down to tell it to create a newline while still keeping things grouped.  A soft break is achieved by putting two trailing spaces at the end of the line you want to end with a new line.

You can check out this tutorial to see what I mean.
http://www.markdowntutorial.com/lesson/7/

Additionally, be aware of what editor you are using.  It might be removing trailing spaces!
[Trailing spaces removed on Python heredoc lines in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701782/trailing-spaces-removed-on-python-heredoc-lines-in-pycharm)

```
"""
I am a description of what a method does

:param param1: an integer  <-- line ends right here with two spaces
:param param2: a str
"""
```

Comment: @canhazbits haha thanks. I’ll take an upvote though!